# How to exclude temporary Xcode files from Time Machine?

Tags: xcode, timemachine

I write a lot of code using Xcode. I know Xcode creates temporary files when it builds. These seem to be quite large (GB's), and I would like to exclude them from Time Machine backups.

How can I exclude them ? Where are they located? Is the location always the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Launch System Preferences
2. Select Time Machine
3. Click Options...
4. Add `~/Library/Developer` to exclusion list
5. Click Save

[image: demo]

Comment: But won't that exclude other useful stuff like simulators etc ? I just want to exclude just the data generated when I build a project in Xcode.....

Comment: It is my settings just for demo, but U can select any separated subfolders from that location, like *DerivedData*, etc.

Comment: You can add just DerivedData: `Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`, but I wouldn't say that simulators are useful to backup.

Comment: I would like to backup anything which otherwise Xcode would have to download from the internet. Things which can be generated by just doing a build, I don't need to backup.

Comment: Note that most of those items are already excluded from Time Machine backups; see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 5):

For the most part, these items are already excluded from Time Machine backups, through the use of the HFS+/APFS `com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem` extended attribute bit that is set for build-related directories in these folders.

Take, for instance, the following:

```
mdouma46@MacBookPro15 ~ % ls -l@e ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator        
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@  4 mdouma46  staff   128 Mar  6  2021 Caches
    com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem   61 
drwxr-xr-x  65 mdouma46  staff  2080 Jan  2 10:38 Devices
drwxr-xr-x   3 mdouma46  staff    96 Nov 28  2020 Temp
```

This shows the `CoreSimulator/Caches` directory has the `com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem` extended attribute set with the binary plist version of the following XML plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<string>com.apple.backupd</string>
</plist>
```

This effectively excludes this folder and contents from Time Machine backups. Likewise, the directories inside `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices` all have the same `com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem` extended attribute set. Most stuff in the DerivedData is also excluded (save `Unsaved_Xcode_Documents`).

Note that `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData` contains your CodeSnippets, Custom Key bindings, font and color themes, and other data that you'd likely want backed up.

Apple's pretty good about excluding that kind of stuff from backups automatically.

Also of note is that I believe the `.nobackup` suffix can be used on directories to prevent the contents from being backed up, and similarly, `.noindex` to prevent the contents from being indexed by Spotlight.